# `std::promise::set_value` modifies given value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, promise

I have a `std::promise`. I call `set_value` and pass in an object. It's a tuple containing a single custom object with two member variables.

This eventually calls `_Set_value_raw`  inside `std::_Associated_state`.

```cpp
void _Set_value_raw(_Ty&& _Val, unique_lock<mutex>* _Lock,     bool _At_thread_exit) { 
    if (_Has_stored_result) {        
        _Throw_future_error(make_error_code(future_errc::promise_already_satisfied));     
    }     
 
    _Result = _STD forward<_Ty>(_Val); 
    _Do_notify(_Lock, _At_thread_exit); 
}
```

`_Val` is the object I passed into `std::promise::set_value`, and it has the following value (slightly redacted to make it easier to read):

`_Val = ({mFoo=unique_ptr {...}, mBar=unique_ptr {...}})`

This is great. `_Result = _STD forward<_Ty>(_Val);` will execute, and the promise will contain my object. However, if I check the value of `_Result` after that line executes, my object has changed.

`_Result = ({mFoo=empty, mBar=unique_ptr {...}})`

One of the object's underlying member variables (`mFoo`) is now empty or a `nullptr`.

This only happens with Visual-C++. The issue does not happen with Clang.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Since the behaviour differs across compilers, this is probably a manifestation of some Undefined Behaviour in your code. Unfortunately, you shared very little details. Please try to reduce the example (your actual code, not a fragment of the standard library) to as little as possible and share it via editing your question.

Comment: Can you show your code where you're setting the `std::promise`'s value?

Comment: Probably a bad assignment operator or rule of 5 mistake.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont was spot on. `Foo` has a bad assignment operator. I only saw this on Windows because only Windows creates empty objects when constructing a promise.